# Questions about Views

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2008-r2

I support SQL Servers 2000 thru 2008R2 (all Standard Edition).

**Question 1**

Please consider the following hypothetical situation. Let's say you have a 5 table view, with the tables inner joined. Let's further assume that I am pulling 10 fields from each table, so I have a View with a total of 50 fields in it. If I selected only 2 fields from the view (one in each of two of the tables), would that query be slower than the equivalent table join script assuming you had all the same tables and joins?

**Question 2**

What if I created a generic view with a script like this:

```
Create View SomeView
AS

select * from SomeTable
Go
```

These tables have fields added to them fairly regularly. Each time I add a field to "SomeTable" the view would automatically work, correct? Is this appreciably slower 
if I SomeTable had 50 fields and I selected two of them from the generic view? If I select two fields from the Select * view, will it only query for those fields?

Question 3
If I create a view like the following

```
Create View Blah
AS
select (some fields) 
from TableA join TableB on TableA.Blah = TableB.Blah
Go
```

Then I use the view like this:

```
Select (some fields) from dbo.Blah where SomeDate >= '1/1/2008'
```

Will I lose any performance? Will the optimizer actually only pull view records that apply or will it pull all and then sub select the result set?

TIA.

Comment: Don't ever create a view with `select *` in it - it is a really bad idea, as you may get different data values/types back than you expect if the underlying tables are changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Each time I add a field to "SomeTable" the view would automatically work, correct?

No, see here [how to make sure that the view will have the underlying table changes by using sp_refreshview](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-make-sure-that-the-view-will-have)

> > Will the optimizer actually only pull view records that apply or will it pull all and then sub select the result set?

A view is nothing but a stored query, the optimizer is smart enough to do a range seek or scan on just the data it needs, you can verify this by looking at the execution plan

> > so I have a View with a total of 50 fields in it. If I selected only 2 fields from the view (one in each of two of the tables), would that query be slower than the equivalent table join script assuming you had all the same tables and joins?

again run stats io or time against the query with * and just 2 columns and look if you see a difference in reads and time

so for example

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
GO

SELECT * FROM SomeView

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
GO



SET STATISTICS IO ON
GO

SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM SomeView

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
GO
```

Comment: Rather than relying upon remembering to use `sp_refreshview`, never use `select *` in a view — the results could be disasterous!

Comment: Correct..it is also the last line in that blog post